# transform hex to binary and vice versa, but keeping them as integers

Tags: python, string, binary, integer, hex

I know how to transform a hexadecimal integer into a binary string using the bin function, but is there an easy way to transform a hex integer into a binary **integer**?

Phrased differently, is there an easy way to transform the string representation of a binary integer (`"0b111"`) into an integer representing a binary integer (`0b111`)

Using bin() results in a hexadecimal string

```
>>> bin(0x7)
'0b111'
>>> type(bin(0x7))
<class 'str'>
```

But what I want to achieve is this:

```
>>> magic(0x7)
0b111
>>> type(magic(0x7))
<class 'int'>
```

(The magic function is just a placeholder, essentially I want a way to transform the string representation of the binary integer into a binary integer)

- **Question 1:** Is this somehow possible, if yes how?
- **Question 2:** Does it make sense to do so? Is it better to work with string representations or integer representations of hexadecimal and binary numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between the what you call a 'hexadecimal integer', and  a 'binary integer' - they are both just integers:

```
>>> 0x07
7
>>> 0b111
7
>>> type(0x07)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(0b111)
<type 'int'>
>>> 0x07 == 0b111
True
>>> 0x07 is 0b111  # This is true in the special case of small integers
True
```

The `0x` or `0b` prefix is just a way for you to tell the interpreter how to read the input you provided.

As for converting a binary string representation of an integer into an actual integer, you can do so with `int(string, base)`:

```
>>> int('0b111', 2)
7
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly there is no need to differentiate between `0x111` and `7` as the compiler treats both as the same thing?

Comment: To make it more clear, the output of `>>> int('0b111', 2)` with output `7` would be exactly the same for the compiler than `>>> magic('0b111', 2)` with output `0b111`

Comment: (my last comment was formulated as a question, but I forgot the question mark)

Comment: Yes. `0x07`, `0b111` and `7` are all exactly the same in the eyes of the interpreter.